# Dart check if an IP is outside your local network IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: dart, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I can't figure out how to know if an IP, IPv4 or either IPv6, is in my local network.

I'm coding a program LAN and Internet based and I want to prevent it to call some endpoints from outside the network.

So I thought that before do the call just check if the address is local or not.

Thanks.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) has a section that explains that. Basically, you bitwise `AND` both your address and the destination address with your network mask. If the results are equal, then you are on the same network.

Comment: So basically I have to: get both ip address in byte format and then `if( ipLocal & ipRemote == 1) print("Same local network");' ?

Comment: No, you do a bitwise `AND` of the local and mask, and compare that result to a bitwise `AND` of the remote and the same mask. If the result of the comparison of the result of bot address `AND`s with the mask, then the destination is on the same network.

Comment: Oh of course, I understand, but I don't have the netmask of the remote. Should I assume that is the same as mine?

Comment: You do not need the remote network, only the destination address that goes on the packet.

Comment: I'll post the result when I code it, thanks